# How to change mat-tab after routeParams changed?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing, mat-tab

I'm trying to reset `mat-tab-group` to set first tab as active when `routeParams` changed.

**ts file**:

```
public index = 0;

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe((routeParams: Params) => {
    // some code

    this.index = 0;
  });
}
```

**html file**

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="index">
  <mat-tab></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    <a [routerLink]="['/url/2']"></a>
  </mat-tab>
```

In the second tab I have a router link to another card - so, when router navigates to this card component doesn't reloaded (route is `/url/:id`).
But first tab doesn't become active - even if I set index inside subscription on route params.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#active-router-links

Comment: If you provide a stackblitz, this will help for others to understand and help solving your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I did it.
The reason was in two way binding for selectedIndex.

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10282

I set `<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="index">` instead of `<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="index">` and it works.

So, when I go by routerLink from second tab of one card to another card, then first tab of new card becomes active.